# Unclear difference between progress output in TensorFlow 2.3.0 and 1.15.0 in same code

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am new in ML. I have installed two tensorflows in two anaconda environments 1.15.0 and 2.3.0. (1.15.0 for be able to use my old GTX 660 videocard) and saw the difference in output progress info when training the same model.

Сode from book "Deep Learning with Python" by François Chollet:

```
import numpy as np

import os
data_dir='C:/Users/Username/_JupyterDocs/sund/data'
fname = os.path.join(data_dir, 'jena_climate_2009_2016.csv')

os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"

f = open(fname)
data = f.read()
f.close()

lines = data.split('\n')
header = lines[0].split(',')
lines = lines[1:]

float_data = np.zeros((len(lines), len(header) - 1))

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    values = [float(x) for x in line.split(',')[1:]]
    float_data[i, :] = values
    
mean = float_data[:200000].mean(axis=0)
float_data -= mean
std = float_data[:200000].std(axis=0)
float_data /= std

def generator(data, lookback, delay, min_index, max_index, shuffle=False, batch_size=128, step=6):
    if max_index is None:
        max_index = len(data) - delay - 1
    i = min_index + lookback
    while 1:
        if shuffle:
            rows = np.random.randint(min_index + lookback, max_index, size=batch_size)
        else:
            if i + batch_size >= max_index:
                i = min_index + lookback
            rows = np.arange(i, min(i + batch_size, max_index))
            i += len(rows)
        samples = np.zeros((len(rows), lookback // step, data.shape[-1]))
        targets = np.zeros((len(rows),))
        for j, row in enumerate(rows):
            indices = range(rows[j] - lookback, rows[j], step)
            samples[j] = data[indices]
            targets[j] = data[rows[j] + delay ][1]
        yield samples, targets

lookback = 1440
step = 6
delay = 144
batch_size = 128

train_gen = generator(float_data,
                      lookback=lookback,
                      delay=delay,
                      min_index=0,
                      max_index=200000,
                      shuffle=True,
                      step=step,
                      batch_size=batch_size)
val_gen = generator(float_data,
                    lookback=lookback,
                    delay=delay,
                    min_index=200001,
                    max_index=300000,
                    step=step,
                    batch_size=batch_size)
test_gen = generator(float_data,
                     lookback=lookback,
                     delay=delay,
                     min_index=300001,
                     max_index=None,
                     step=step,
                     batch_size=batch_size)

val_steps = (300000 - 200001 - lookback) // batch_size
test_steps = (len(float_data) - 300001 - lookback) // batch_size


import time

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.GRU(32, input_shape=(None, float_data.shape[-1])))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(), loss='mae')

start = time.perf_counter()
history = model.fit_generator(train_gen,
                              steps_per_epoch=500,
                              epochs=20,
                              validation_data=val_gen,
                              validation_steps=val_steps,
                              verbose=1)
elapsed = time.perf_counter() - start

f = open("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/log1.txt", "a")
f.write('Elapsed %.3f seconds.' % elapsed)
f.close()

print('Elapsed %.3f seconds.' % elapsed)
```

TF 2.3.0 progress output:

-Warning about deprecated in output:

> WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10804/2601851929.py:13: Model.fit_generator (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Please use Model.fit, which supports generators.

-Output:

```
Epoch 1/20
500/500 [==============================] - 45s 89ms/step - loss: 0.3050 - val_loss: 0.2686
Epoch 2/20
500/500 [==============================] - 45s 90ms/step - loss: 0.2841 - val_loss: 0.2658
Epoch 3/20
500/500 [==============================] - 46s 92ms/step - loss: 0.2771 - val_loss: 0.2653
Epoch 4/20
500/500 [==============================] - 46s 91ms/step - loss: 0.2729 - val_loss: 0.2795
Epoch 5/20
500/500 [==============================] - 45s 90ms/step - loss: 0.2690 - val_loss: 0.2644
Epoch 6/20
500/500 [==============================] - 45s 90ms/step - loss: 0.2632 - val_loss: 0.2673
Epoch 7/20
500/500 [==============================] - 45s 90ms/step - loss: 0.2602 - val_loss: 0.2641
Epoch 8/20
500/500 [==============================] - 45s 90ms/step - loss: 0.2549 - val_loss: 0.2667
Epoch 9/20
500/500 [==============================] - 45s 91ms/step - loss: 0.2507 - val_loss: 0.2768
Epoch 10/20
500/500 [==============================] - 45s 90ms/step - loss: 0.2447 - val_loss: 0.2785
Epoch 11/20
500/500 [==============================] - 45s 90ms/step - loss: 0.2422 - val_loss: 0.2763
Epoch 12/20
500/500 [==============================] - 45s 90ms/step - loss: 0.2354 - val_loss: 0.2794
Epoch 13/20
500/500 [==============================] - 46s 92ms/step - loss: 0.2320 - val_loss: 0.2807
Epoch 14/20
500/500 [==============================] - 45s 89ms/step - loss: 0.2277 - val_loss: 0.2848
Epoch 15/20
500/500 [==============================] - 45s 90ms/step - loss: 0.2222 - val_loss: 0.2909
Epoch 16/20
500/500 [==============================] - 45s 90ms/step - loss: 0.2178 - val_loss: 0.2910
Epoch 17/20
500/500 [==============================] - 45s 89ms/step - loss: 0.2152 - val_loss: 0.2918
Epoch 18/20
500/500 [==============================] - 45s 90ms/step - loss: 0.2112 - val_loss: 0.2917
Epoch 19/20
500/500 [==============================] - 44s 89ms/step - loss: 0.2103 - val_loss: 0.2979
Epoch 20/20
500/500 [==============================] - 45s 89ms/step - loss: 0.2068 - val_loss: 0.2986
Elapsed 904.779 seconds.
```

TF 1.15.0 progress output:

-Warning about deprecated in output:

> WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Username\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py:1630: calling BaseResourceVariable.**init** (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.

Output:

```
Epoch 1/20
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Username\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\math_grad.py:1424: where (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3014Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 22ms/step - loss: 0.2285
500/500 [==============================] - 63s 126ms/step - loss: 0.3014 - val_loss: 0.2686
Epoch 2/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2836Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 22ms/step - loss: 0.2225
500/500 [==============================] - 62s 123ms/step - loss: 0.2836 - val_loss: 0.2667
Epoch 3/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2761Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 22ms/step - loss: 0.3162
500/500 [==============================] - 62s 123ms/step - loss: 0.2762 - val_loss: 0.2721
Epoch 4/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2731Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 16s 21ms/step - loss: 0.2422
500/500 [==============================] - 62s 124ms/step - loss: 0.2730 - val_loss: 0.2667
Epoch 5/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2667Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 16s 21ms/step - loss: 0.3732
500/500 [==============================] - 61s 122ms/step - loss: 0.2667 - val_loss: 0.2663
Epoch 6/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2613Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 22ms/step - loss: 0.2088
500/500 [==============================] - 62s 124ms/step - loss: 0.2613 - val_loss: 0.2648
Epoch 7/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2544Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 22ms/step - loss: 0.3043
500/500 [==============================] - 62s 125ms/step - loss: 0.2544 - val_loss: 0.2710
Epoch 8/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2493Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 22ms/step - loss: 0.2767
500/500 [==============================] - 63s 127ms/step - loss: 0.2493 - val_loss: 0.2717
Epoch 9/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2455Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 22ms/step - loss: 0.2336
500/500 [==============================] - 62s 124ms/step - loss: 0.2455 - val_loss: 0.2743
Epoch 10/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2406Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 22ms/step - loss: 0.3041
500/500 [==============================] - 63s 126ms/step - loss: 0.2406 - val_loss: 0.2776
Epoch 11/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2345Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 22ms/step - loss: 0.2655
500/500 [==============================] - 62s 124ms/step - loss: 0.2344 - val_loss: 0.2779
Epoch 12/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2310Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 22ms/step - loss: 0.3085
500/500 [==============================] - 62s 124ms/step - loss: 0.2310 - val_loss: 0.2800
Epoch 13/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2271Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 22ms/step - loss: 0.3029
500/500 [==============================] - 64s 127ms/step - loss: 0.2271 - val_loss: 0.2839
Epoch 14/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2226Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 22ms/step - loss: 0.3110
500/500 [==============================] - 62s 125ms/step - loss: 0.2226 - val_loss: 0.2886
Epoch 15/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2190Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 22ms/step - loss: 0.3329
500/500 [==============================] - 62s 123ms/step - loss: 0.2190 - val_loss: 0.2919
Epoch 16/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2170Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 22ms/step - loss: 0.3022
500/500 [==============================] - 62s 125ms/step - loss: 0.2170 - val_loss: 0.2937
Epoch 17/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2132Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 22ms/step - loss: 0.2463
500/500 [==============================] - 62s 124ms/step - loss: 0.2132 - val_loss: 0.3004
Epoch 18/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2101Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 22ms/step - loss: 0.3423
500/500 [==============================] - 62s 124ms/step - loss: 0.2101 - val_loss: 0.3018
Epoch 19/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2072Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 23ms/step - loss: 0.2689
500/500 [==============================] - 62s 125ms/step - loss: 0.2073 - val_loss: 0.3045
Epoch 20/20
499/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2066Epoch 1/20
769/500 [==============================================] - 17s 22ms/step - loss: 0.2809
500/500 [==============================] - 62s 124ms/step - loss: 0.2066 - val_loss: 0.2978
Elapsed 1245.008 seconds.
```

What the two additional progress bar in each epoch in TF 1.15.0 output?

Answer (score 0):

From Documentation:

> verbose: Integer. 0, 1, or 2. Verbosity mode. 0 = silent, 1 = progress
> bar, 2 = one line per epoch

Default is 1.

and this is internal TensorFlow warning, you can safely ignore. which is tell us about future versions of TensorFlow, no actions from your side is needed.

Comment: Yes verbos is 1. But in both cases(2.3.0 and 1.15.0). Code the same but output differnt. And time different (904.779 and 1245.008). I mean may be this is not just differnse in output. Is it possible TF 1.15.0 excuting additional work in same code?